# LX10 Battery Hack to external battery or USB port?

Tags: battery, panasonic-lumix, panasonic

I just got a Lumix LX10 and the battery life is abysmal when running cellphone remote control through wifi, which I need to do because I have a physical disability.

How hard would it be to rig up an external battery or convert it into a USB port that I could plug into a power hub?

I have been looking up videos and it seems that most with cameras if you take apart a battery pack there's a board that connects to lithium cells. Can you just remove the cells and attach a wire to each connector that runs outside the camera to either a 7.4v battery or something that regulates it to that volage? Or is there some safety mechanism in Panasonic cameras that would stop that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No need to hack up something yourself, this already exists, google for "DMW-BLH7E BLH7 Dummy Battery DMW-DCC15" (around $20 on Amazon US).

Comment: Also known as a "DC Coupler".

Comment: Oh wow! TY! Follow me on IG @brinzerdecalli if you want to see what inspired creations you have enabled!